# What do you call someone who receives a commendation

Tags: antonyms

According to [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commender), a "commender" commends someone. What do you call someone who receives a commendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a *commendee*. If you look [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ee) (definition 1) you'll see that by adding the noun suffix -ee you can make someone or something the recipient of a specified action, in this case the action of being commended.

Comment: Interesting. The *noun* suffix is affixed to a *verb* (to turn it into a noun).

Comment: @Lawrence  Just like [addressee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addressee).

Comment: @Lawrence And [payee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/payee).

Comment: Indeed. I wonder why it’s not called a *verb* suffix.

Comment: @Lawrence I’d say it is a *noun* suffix because, ultimately, the suffix will be at the end of a noun; once it has been affixed to the verb, the word now becomes a noun.

Comment: @Lawrence Hmmm, "pay" and 'address" can be nouns. I checked a bunch of these words. In the following the stem before suffix -ee can be noun: interviewee, employee, licensee, internee, mortgagee, arrestee, divorcee, escapee, refugee, franchisee, trustee. But ones where the suffix is attached to only a verb are ones like: deportee, detainee, referee, abductee, attendee, appointee. I think there was only one I found that was only an adjective, and that was absentee.

Comment: @Zebrafish Hmm, the -ee/-or relationship seems to be intrinsically bound to the verb (e.g. *employ*). Although the same word might also be a noun, that might simply be happenstance. With *absentee*, there's no \**absentor*, so I'd exclude that from the current discussion.

Comment: @Lawrence Yeah I think you're right, the tendency is to place it on the verb. I'm pretty sure this is from French. In French the ée suffix is the feminine past participle, so in the same way we use the past participle to mean a thing or person who has (so to speak) done the verb or had the verb happen to them, ie., depart/ the departed, French does the same thing with either é or ée. emigrée is a past participle in French, corresponding to our "emigrated".